# how do i make visible other component visible while setting background image of frame?

Tags: java, swing, bufferedimage, paintcomponent

i am setting frame's background image when i run program my other components are invisible only image is visible in frame

```
class ImagePanel extends JComponent {
private Image image;
public ImagePanel(Image image) {
    this.image = image;
}
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
}
```

In the main class I  call the above class as shown below:

```
BufferedImage myImage = ImageIO.read(new File("cal.jpg"));
frame.setContentPane(new ImagePanel(myImage));
```

Answer (score 2):

You have this code:

```
BufferedImage myImage = ImageIO.read(new File("cal.jpg"));
frame.setContentPane(new ImagePanel(myImage));
```

but you appear to be creating the ImagePanel instance *inline*, and don't appear to be adding any components to this ImagePanel instance, so I'm not surprised that you're not seeing any components. You also don't seem to be adding any components to it in the ImagePanel constructor.

Consider adding components to the ImagePanel class within its constructor, or in the class that uses it, create an ImagePanel instance, assign it to a variable, add components to it, and **then** place it into the JFrame's contentPane.

Side recommendations:

- Consider getting your image as a Jar resource and not as a File, since likely you will Jar the classes at some point, and if you continue using File, your image might not be reachable.
- Make sure to give your ImagePanel a decent layout manager. I believe that JComponents use `null` layouts by default, something that you don't want to use.

For example, this worked for me:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestImagePanel {
    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        String resource = "/imgFolder/PlanetEarth.jpg";
        Image image = null;
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(TestImagePanel.class.getResource(resource));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        ImagePanel mainPanel = new ImagePanel(image);
        mainPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        mainPanel.add(new JButton("Fubars Rule!"));

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TestImagePanel");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class ImagePanel extends JComponent {
    private Image image;

    public ImagePanel(Image image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        Dimension superSize = super.getPreferredSize();
        int w = image == null ? superSize.width : Math.max(superSize.width, image.getWidth(null));
        int h = image == null ? superSize.height : Math.max(superSize.height, image.getHeight(null));
        Dimension d = new Dimension(w, h);

        return d;
    }
}
```

and showed this GUI:

[image]

Comment: Actually i m working in gui and i added labels into frame but they r not showing when i add background image

Comment: @HamzaShahid: Thanks for getting back to us on this. Then there's likely something wrong with your code but it's not shown here with your question. Consider creating and posting your [mcve] (please check out the link).

Comment: actually my code is running good and it shows result perfeclty before i added code for background image after that my other components are just not showing

Comment: is there some specific layout for background image ?

Comment: @HamzaShahid: layouts have nothing to do with this. The issue again is that you have a bug in code not shown. Your current code again shows you using the ImagePanel without adding any components to it, so based on that code, that's your problem. If you've fixed that, then something else is going on, and again you'll need to post a small [mcve] demonstrateion program.